# Better action hook for creating table than after_switch_theme and switch_theme action hook

Tags: actions, table

I want to create table only if my custom theme is activated. I have tried with `after_switch_theme` action hook but it is creating table regardless my custom theme. This means it is triggering action if I activate `Twenty fifteen` or any other theme.

```
add_action('after_switch_theme', ['\Recruitment\recruitment', 'create_table']);
```

I want to create table only if my custom theme is a current theme or activating that theme.

Is there any hook for it or any alternate way?

Comment: To be clear - your call to to `add_action()` is in your custom theme's `functions.php` (or another file included therein), correct?

Comment: @bosco yes, that's correct. However, my problem is not where to call but which action hook to be used. Can you please help me?

Comment: Certainly - I was just making sure you weren't calling it in a plugin, since it running as you describe (even when swapping to third-party themes) seems to contradict the Codex's description of the action. It wouldn't be the first time the Codex has been misleading, though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah I found it.

You can use `after_setup_theme` action hook. So it will be like

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', ['\Recruitment\recruitment', 'create_table']);
```

## Updated Code

```
$theme = wp_get_theme();

if ( $theme->name == 'My THEME NAME' ) {

  global $wpdb;
  global $charset_collate;

  $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ... $charset_collate;";

  require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php';
  dbDelta( $sql );

  add_option( 'ab_db_version', self::$db_version );

}

// in another file

add_action('after_switch_theme', ['\Recruitment\recruitment', 'create_table']);
```

Comment: `after_setup_theme` runs on every page load - if you choose to go this route and use some sort of check to see if the table already exists before creating, keep it mind those database transactions will come with a little overhead.

Comment: @bosco oh yeah, I didn't realize that. Thank you so much for your input. Do you have any other hook?

Comment: I think you were on the right path the first time, we just need to add a little extra logic :) . One minute

Comment: @bosco I have updated my answer code.. what do you think about it?

Comment: The updated code is working fine. It is creating table if and only my current theme is getting activated. But I need some feedback whether it is right approach or not.

Comment: You nailed it - your updated code is pretty much what I was going to suggest. The only thing I might change is checking `$theme->stylesheet_dir` against your theme's programmatically obtained root directory, as theme names could theoretically collide but stylesheet directories really cannot. But I'm going to take a closer look at the the `after_switch_theme` hook this weekend and see if I can't figure out what's up, seeings as the way the Codex describes it, we shouldn't need either theme check.

Comment: Admittedly, I'm not terribly familiar with this action. One other thing you might want to check is that you're comfortable with whatever happens when the table does not exist and your theme is not activated, but you "preview" the theme from the dashboard.

Comment: @bosco thanks once again for a suggestion. I think you have a point by checking stylesheet directory instead of theme name. Did you get time to check more in it? please let me know if you found any better solution than what I have done..